# I can't run jobs on PgAgent on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jobs, pgagent

I installed pgagent on Ubuntu 16.04.

I executed:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgagent;
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

According this: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/1.x/pgagent_install.htm

I ran

```
/usr/bin/pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 user=my_user password=*****
```

And created my jobs:

[image: Jobs print]

But, when I try to execute, nothing happens. No error, messages, nothing. And functions are not executed.

I do not know where to start solving this

Comment: Any news? I got the same problem on Windows server 2012

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread, but for the sake of helping other people having this issue, here is a suggestion:

I'm not sure if pgAgent accepts passwords like this, which would mean the password would be visible via a simple `ps aux` command. Instead, you need to use a pgpass file:

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ cd ~
$ nano .pgpass

# Insert the following text and save the document:
localhost:5432:*:postgres:[postgres_password]

$ chmod 0600 .pgpass

$ pgagent hostaddr=localhost dbname=postgres user=postgres
```